# SSH config with PhpStorm and built-in or native SSH executable option

Tags: ssh, windows-10, phpstorm

In case of Built-in or Native selected option of SSH Executable in `PhpStorm > Version Control > Git option` :

- where is the config of SSH ?
- what is the difference between those options ?

[image]

I would like to custom my SSH for few tricks development...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH configuration is located in a standard place - `~/.ssh`. On Windows it is resolved to `C:\Users\your username\.ssh`.

Difference between built-in and native executables is described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-git-integration.html.